# Im trying to output all the data from my database and there is an error in the foreach statement

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to output all the data from the database, but I have this error at my foreach statement that I cant solve for 2 days

Controller file:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        PAPEntities db = new PAPEntities();
        MoviesData[] movies = db.MoviesData.ToArray();

        movies.Select(movie => new MovieViewModels
        {
            MovieID = movie.MovieID,
            MovieName = movie.MovieName,
            MovieDescription = movie.MovieDescription,
            MoviePrice = movie.MoviePrice,
            MovieCategory = movie.MovieCategory,
            MovieYear = movie.MovieYear
        });


        return View(movies);
    }
```

The View:

```
 <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive table-hover">
    <tr>
        <th><b>Movie Name </b></th>
        <th><b>Movie Category </b></th>
        <th><b>Movie Year </b></th>
        <th><b>Movie Price</b></th>

    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.MovieName</td>
            <td>@item.MovieCategory</td>
            <td>@item.MovieYear
            <td>@item.MoviePrice</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

The model is a simple class caled MovieViewModel with 6 properties

foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'MovieViewModels' because 'MovieViewModels' does not contain a public instance definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Comment: Please show how your view declares what its model should be. I suspect that's the problem. Also note that your `Select` call isn't actually going to do anything.... that's not how LINQ works. I suspect you want `var movies = db.MoviesData.Select(movie => new MovieViewModels { ... }).ToList();` or similar.

Comment: what is the `@model` on the view? i.e. what is the `Model` typed as? I suspect it is `MovieViewModels`, when it should be `IEnumerable<MovieViewModels>` (note: a list or array would probably be better, but that needs corresponding changes to your `Index()` method too). As a side note: calling something `MovieViewModels` when it only represents a single item is bound to cause confusion - `MovieViewModel` would be better. Edit: as Jon notes, you need changes to `Index()` *anyway*, since you're not capturing the return of `Select`

Comment: Currently it is without the IEnumerable, but I tried with the IEnumerable<> aswell and it didnt work, I will try the way you are saying and give you a feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few points here:

1. you aren't capturing the result of `Select`
2. presumably your view doesn't have the correct model definition

For 1, note that you should project *before* buffering - there's no point creating *actual* instances of the `MoviesData` object, if LINQ can bypass it in the projection, so:

(note: I took the liberty of renaming `MovieViewModels` to `MovieViewModel`)

```cs
MovieViewModel[] movies = db.MoviesData.Select(movie => new MovieViewModel
{
    MovieID = movie.MovieID,
    MovieName = movie.MovieName,
    MovieDescription = movie.MovieDescription,
    MoviePrice = movie.MoviePrice,
    MovieCategory = movie.MovieCategory,
    MovieYear = movie.MovieYear
}).ToArray();

return View(movies);
```

(this also means the SQL might be limited to just the columns that you're interested in, avoiding fetching unnecessary columns)

Then in the view, you should have:

```cs
@model MovieViewModel[]
```

which tells razor the type to use for `Model`.

With that: things should work.

Comment: I know im not supposed to say thanks in a comment, however im just a starter (you probably noticed) and i really need to thank to the people that take some of their time to help a newbie. thank you and to all that tried to help

Comment: @DiogoTeixeira saying "thanks" is not against any rules, and comments are perfectly appropriate for that :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the select select statement you are using. `Select` does not return the result until you apply a get result function on it. e.g `ToList()` or `ToArray()` etc.

[image]

You need to apply the `ToArray()` method after the select statement to get result in enumrator.

```
MovieViewModel[] movies = db.MoviesData.Select(movie => new MovieViewModel
{
    MovieID = movie.MovieID,
    MovieName = movie.MovieName,
    MovieDescription = movie.MovieDescription,
    MoviePrice = movie.MoviePrice,
    MovieCategory = movie.MovieCategory,
    MovieYear = movie.MovieYear
}).ToArray();
```